# google map API in html in a web browser in vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, google-maps

I am working on a program that utilizes the google map, added with markers that has an addListener event.

I am at no good in html, so, what I will do is to create a basic html file that contain all the markers with addListeners in it to call a cctv camera. as of now, its working inside that html file.

but what I wanted to do is incorporate it in VB, put a web browser in winForms, navigate to the site. here comes my question, how can VB recognize the mouse click event in the marker?
[image]

this is the html that I made, that's a marker, changed it to my icon. so what I want, is when I click on that marker, it will trigger an event or maybe a button in VB.

I use this code to call a button in the web browser using a button in vb. 
`web.Document.All("mConnect").InvokeMember("click")`
can I make something vice versa?

hope you guys can help thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML-Javascript can recognise mouse clicks within their region, all you have to do then is communicate the event across to your VB.Net application.

The link below shows to how to call functions from Javascript to VB.Net and vice versa.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks! it gave me exactly what I need. I was looking on this for hours. :)